# Prometheus / Grafana replace label in one metric with value from another

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Basically on the dashboard I need to label the processes we are monitoring from windows_exporter with the name from windows_service_info

Comment: Please provide sample of the data, the expected result and what you have tried so far. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the metrics by a common label.  Take a look [here](https://www.robustperception.io/left-joins-in-promql) for details, since you didn't provide any details of your metrics